# Getting random data from Arduino using esp32 and Insert it in SQL Server using PHP

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, arduino, esp32

```
<?php
$serverName = "";
$connectionOptions = array(
"Database" =\> "",
"UID" =\> "",
"PWD" =\> "",
);

$conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionOptions);

if ($conn === false) {
die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

echo "Connection Success!<br>";

if (isset($\_GET\['Value1'\]) || isset($\_GET\['Value2'\])) {

    $value1 = isset($_GET['Value1']) ? $_GET['Value1'] : null;
    $value2 = isset($_GET['Value2']) ? $_GET['Value2'] : null;
    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO dbo.ESP (Value1, Value2) VALUES (?, ?)";
    $params = array($value1, $value2);
    
    $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);
    
    if ($result === false) {
        echo "Error inserting data: " . print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true);
    } else {
        echo "Data inserted into Value1: " . $value1 . " and Value2: " . $value2;
    }

} else {
echo "Either Value1 or Value2 data must be provided in the request.";

}

sqlsrv_close($conn);
?\>
```

Why am I getting a Null value in VALUE2 after getting random data(arduino) in VALUE1?
Here's the table.

| Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- |
| manaqg | NULL |
| mgjxm | NULL |
| NULL | vuwhn |
| NULL | bjmnc |

(Table 1.)

Can someone help me or explain to me how can I get the value like this

| Value1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- |
| manaqg | vuwhn |
| mgjxm | bjmnc |

(Table 2.)

I want the value 2 to be placed in the same row of the value 1 column. Like in the Table 2.

Comment: How are requests to this PHP page being made?  That's probably more relevant.  In essence, the code you've provided here seems like it would achieve what you're after - provided the request/s being made to the page are providing the "Value1" and "Value2" values together in the same request.  My immediate suspicion is that your requests are doing this properly

Comment: @Craig The ESP32 is making HTTP GET requests to a PHP page using the HTTPClient library. It is set up to send data to a PHP script hosted on a server, and the PHP script processes the data and interacts with a database.

Comment: You should make your ESP32 code (i.e. the source of the data) robust and send whatever it *should* store in the database. Why the ESP32 wasting communication time and bandwidth sending NULL? The PHP code should simply take whatever it is received and store it, not to handling data manipulation and business logic before storing the data.

Comment: Your requests are obviously coming separately, it seems - one request with Value1 set and then a separate request with Value2 set.  In that case, how are you expecting your PHP code to understand which "Value2" belongs with which "Value1"?  I think you need to look at your application as a whole - it does not really seem that your PHP page, itself, is the problem.  Your PHP can only take the data it is given and put that data into the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Please use AND operator instead of OR.

```
if(isset($_GET['Value1']) && isset($_GET['Value2'])) {
 // insert
}
```

2. If you need to generate random data if Value1 or Value2 is null, please use following code.

```
function randStr($l = 8) {
    return substr(md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), true)), 0, $l);
}

$value1 = isset($_GET['Value1']) ? $_GET['Value1'] : randStr();
$value2 = isset($_GET['Value2']) ? $_GET['Value2'] : randStr();

// insert
```

Comment: i tried this method but ii redirect in  

else {
echo "Either Value1 or Value2 data must be provided in the request.";
}

here's the  result in the serial monitor

Inserting in Value1: kcjyo
Server response: Connection Success!<br>Either Value1 or Value2 data must be provided in the request.

Comment: So you need to generate random data if either Value1 or Value2 is null?

Comment: Im getting random data from arduino and I need to place the data of value 2 in its right place which is the same row as value 1, instead the value of value 2 is placed in the opposite row of value 1. You can check the table that I posted above.

Comment: As long as Value1 and Value2 have nothing to do with each other, there is no other way. Please replace Value1 or Value2 to random data if it is null before insert data.